# How-to-unlock-phone-with-pattern-in-appium

Tags: appium, unlock

so we are testing one application in which we need to change the pattern in between the flow to test the flow completely.I even tried this but it did not work:
Integer x_topLeftCorner=257;
        Integer y_topLeftCorner=1235;

```
    Integer x_topRightCorner=572;
    Integer y_topRightCorner=1235;

    Integer x_bottomLeftCorner= 260;
    Integer y_bottomLeftCorner=1438;

    Integer x_bottomRightCorner=532;
    Integer y_bottomRightCorner=1504;

    //Use coordinates to draw the security pattern and unlock the screen 
    TouchAction obj = new TouchAction(MBase.getDriver()); 
    obj.press(x_topLeftCorner,y_topLeftCorner).moveTo(x_topRightCorner,y_topRightCorner).moveTo(x_bottomLeftCorner,y_bottomLeftCorner).moveTo(x_bottomRightCorner,y_bottomRightCorner).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void AndroidLaunchApp() throws MalformedURLException {
    UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
    options.setPlatformName("Android");
    options.setAutomationName(AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
    options.setDeviceName("R5CR11DNX9X");
    options.autoGrantPermissions();
    options.setApp(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/apps/falcon.apk")
            .setUnlockType("pattern")
            .setUnlockKey("74123698");
    try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), options);
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (MalformedURLException | InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Use this in your capabilities section to unlock the device

To active the device use the adb shell command - adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER